# Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object..

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-boot, webpack

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

So Im using react js with spring boot in my application. I have configured webpack successfuly (I think) but the problem I have is after the HTML page is loaded it doesnt render anything in the "div" tag. :(

**App.js**

```
import {React} from 'react';
import {ReactDOM} from 'react-dom';
const client = require('./client');

//import css from "./App.css";
import {NavBar} from './navbar';
import {Home} from './home';
//const index = require('/alpha/src/main/resources/templates/index.html');


const heroImageStyling = {
          height: 200,
          width: 200
        };

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: [
      { id: 1, value: 0, name: "Item 1" },
      { id: 2, value: 0, name: "Item 2" },
      { id: 3, value: 0, name: "Item 3" },
      { id: 4, value: 0, name: "Item 3" },
      { id: 5, value: 0, name: "Item 3" },
      { id: 6, value: 0, name: "Item 4" },
      { id: 7, value: 0, name: "Item 4" },
      { id: 8, value: 0, name: "Item 5" }
    ]
  };


  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {products: []};
    }

   componentDidMount() {
     client({ method: "GET", path: "/" }).done(response => {
       this.setState({ products: response.entity._embedded.products });
     });
   }
  handleDelete = id => {
    console.log("event handled", id);
  };

  handleNavBarCartIncrement = product => {
    const products = [...this.state.products];
    const index = products.indexOf(product);
    products[index] = { ...product };
    products[index].value++;
    this.setState({ products });

    console.log(product);
  };

  render() {
    return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <NavBar
              cartItems={this.state.products.filter(c => c.value > 0).length}
            />
            <main className="container">
              <Home
                products={this.state.products}
                onIncrement={this.handleNavBarCartIncrement}
                onDelete={this.handleDelete}
              />
            </main>
          </React.Fragment>
                );
              }

}

ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('react')
    )
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>ReactJS + Spring Data REST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="react"></div>

    <script src="/built/bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My index.html used to get the react component but did not display anything other than an  tag without anything. But not it doesnt do that either. Now it doesnt retrieve anything but instead it gets the following errors.

Answer (score 0):

You must import React, ReactDom and your classes without curly braces.

If you use export default to export your file, you don't need to put curly braces, if you use only export, then you must use {}

Another thing is that if you don't want to do configure webpack and bable by yourself, you can use `create-react-app` command to create a new react project and all will be set for you.

The command is: **npx create-react-app myApp**